# How to create pandas datafram from a dictionary and keep list in one cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary like:

```
dic = {'c': [14, 41],
       'i': '52983542076720',
       'p': 31.7,
       's': 100,
       't': 1611945588012261376,
       'x': 11}
```

I tried

```
pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

and

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic,, orient='columns', dtype=int, columns=None)
```

However, they all return a 2 rows dataframe like:

|  | c | i | p | s | t | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 14 | 52983542076720 | 31 | 100 | 1611945588012261376 | 11 |
| 1 | 41 | 52983542076720 | 31 | 100 | 1611945588012261376 | 11 |

I actually want to get a dataframe like:

|  | c | i | p | s | t | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [14,41] | 52983542076720 | 31 | 100 | 1611945588012261376 | 11 |

any idea about what I should do to get the result?

Comment: update dic as list of list. Then try `pd.DataFrame`.  i.e., `dic['c']=[dic['c']]` then  `df=pd.DataFrame(dic)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pandas.Series` instead:

```
pd.Series(dic).to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
          c               i     p    s                    t   x
0  [14, 41]  52983542076720  31.7  100  1611945588012261376  11
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`

```
out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0:dic},'index')

Out[238]: 
          c               i     p    s                    t   x
0  [14, 41]  52983542076720  31.7  100  1611945588012261376  11
```